# Integration problem getting a negative answer

Tags: integration

I encounter the following problem:

$$ \int_1^\infty \left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+1}\right)dx $$

I solved the indefinite integral:

$$ \ln x - \ln (x+1) = \ln \left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right) $$

Plugged in bounds I got:

$$ \ln \left(\frac{\infty}{\infty+1}\right) - \ln \left(\frac{1}{1+1}\right) = \ln 1 - \ln \frac{1}{2} = -\ln \frac{1}{2} $$

But apparently the answer suggested in the sheet is $ \ln \frac{1}{2} $. Where did I miss a negative?

Comment: The answer should be positive, and $-\ln\dfrac 1 2$ is the same as $\ln2$, which is positive.  The number $\ln\dfrac12$ cannot be right because it's negative and you're integrating a positive function over a positively oriented interval. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct; note that $\ln(\frac{1}{2})<0$ because $\frac{1}{2}<1$.

It might be better to write the answer as $\ln(2)$, using the fact that $\ln(\frac{1}{x})=-\ln x$.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now! By the way, a related similar question: $\lim_{x \to 0} (\ln (\frac{x}{x+1}))$, why is it equal to negative infinity and not 0?

Comment: $\frac{x}{x+1}\to 0$ as $x\to 0$, and $\ln(t)\to-\infty$ as $t\to 0$.

Comment: Right, got confused there! Thank you!